# Style if input has pseudo="-internal-input-suggested"

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Is it possible to have the same CSS transformation execute when the input has been autofilled using `pseudo="-internal-input-suggested` as it does when the input is focused?

In this case, if the input has been autofilled, then it applies `transform: translatey(-23px);`. Currently if there is any autofilled information in the input, the label covers the input, and only when you tap `body` does the input receive the `focus` state as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input__html {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.input__label {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #868ca0;
}

.input__label .input__span {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  top: 18px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  left: 6px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #868ca0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.input__label .input__focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.input__label input {
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  background: #ffffff00;
  color: #6f6666;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input__label input[value]+.input__span,
.input__label input:valid+.input__span,
.input__label input:not(:placeholder-shown)+.input__span,
.input__label input:focus+.input__span {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-23px);
  transform: translatey(-23px);
  outline: none;
}

.input__label input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input__html">
  <label class="input__label">
    <input name="input" type="text" required autocomplete="username" placeholder="&nbsp;">
    <span class="input__span">Name</span>
    <span class="input__focus"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use ```input:placeholder-shown``` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to access the autocomplete `:-webkit-autofill`:

```
.input__label input:-webkit-autofill + .input__span,
.input__label textarea:-webkit-autofill + .input__span,
```

Comment: Are you sure it's cross-browser?